# How to convert a date from yyyy-mm-dd to Month(in words) day year?

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble in converting this date. What I want is to convert the date formated in yyyy-mm-dd into Month day year. How can I achieve this?
below is my code.

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($news))
{?>
<?php echo $row ["date"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["place"] ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the PHP `date` function to reformat it:

```
echo date('F j, Y',strtotime($row['date']));  // January 30, 2015, for example.
```

See [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for many more formatting options.

Comment: How about if Im going to get the day??

Comment: @DaniloEscapa I'm not sure what you mean. There are many options that you can use in the format string. Take a look at the PHP page I linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Primary objective is to convert your date string (in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd') into timestamp. Timestamp makes it easier / possible for php to convert it into one of many formats that you may desire.

For instance, you want 2015-01-30 to be listed as January 30, 2015, all you need to do is:

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime("2015-01-30");
$formattedDate = date('F d, Y', $timestamp);
echo $formattedDate;
?>
```

You can, however, choose other formats for your presentation from:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date=date('m-d-Y',strtotime($row["date"]));
```

Output would look like this:

```
01-01-2000
```

You can refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more date format and change the value inside the code I have given.

Comment: _'Month(in words)'_ - hmm...

Comment: what will I put to $yourdate?

Comment: @HoboSapiens Well, actually, OP didn't **specify** the format so I just answered it in the order he wants, so that's why I also included a link which has a list of date format for him to check. Clear now?

Comment: How about if Im going to get the day?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(datecol, '%M %d %Y)
```

The complete documentation for the function is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).  It provides a lot of flexibility in the output string format for a date.