# Formatting Date When Sending PHP Form

Tags: php, date, format

Here is my problem. I have a php form that is sent to an email address. Everything works great however the format of the date is yyyy-mm-dd. I would like to have the date be, Month DD, YYYY. What do I need to change in my code to get this to work?

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'email@email.com'; // <-----Put Your email address here.
if (empty($_POST['date']) || empty($_POST['song3']) || 
    empty($_POST['song2']) || empty($_POST['song1'])) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required"; 
}

$date = $_POST['date'];  
$song3 = $_POST['song3'];  
$song2 = $_POST['song2'];  
$song1 = $_POST['song1']; 

if (empty($errors)) {
    $to = $myemail;     
    $email_subject = "Hot 3 at 3- $date";   
    $email_body = "Here is today's Hot 3 at 3.\n\n\n" . "3. $song3 \n\n2. $song2 \n\n1. $song1";
    $headers = "From: KLIA-FM\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";     
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers); // redirect to the 'thank you' page   
    header('Location: thank-you.html'); 
}  
?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html> 
<head>  
    <title>Contactform handler</title>
</head>

<body> <!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
    <?php echo nl2br($errors); ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a date from yyyy-mm-dd to Month(in words) day year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228874/how-to-convert-a-date-from-yyyy-mm-dd-to-monthin-words-day-year)

Answer (score 0):

Change this from:

```
 $date = $_POST['date'];
```

To:

```
$date = date('F d, Y', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Here read below, all the formats:

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$date = date_create($date);
$date = date_format($date,"F,d,Y");
```